# Excelがファイルを使用していることを検知する方法

Tags: c#, windows, excel

Excelがファイルの編集を終えたことを検知したいのですが、Excelプロセスの終了検知も、開いているファイルのリード権をポーリングする方法でも誤検知してしまいます。
確実に編集を終えたことを検知する方法はないのでしょうか。

今のところ想像ですが、
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/981094/ja
の現象で、excelが上書き保存のタイミングでxlsxファイルを一度手離す気がしています。

コードですが以下のような感じで、終了監視しています。

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filename);
if (p != null)
{
   p.WaitForExit();
   while (System.IO.File.Exists(filename))
   {
       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
       try
       {
           using (System.IO.FileStream fs =
               new System.IO.FileStream(
                   filename,
                   System.IO.FileMode.Open,
                   System.IO.FileAccess.Read,
                   System.IO.FileShare.None))
           {
               break;
           }
       }
       catch
       {
           continue;
       }
   }
}
else
{
   while (System.IO.File.Exists(filename))
   {
       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
       try
       {
           using (System.IO.FileStream fs =
               new System.IO.FileStream(
                   filename,
                   System.IO.FileMode.Open,
                   System.IO.FileAccess.Read,
                   System.IO.FileShare.None))
           {
               break;
           }
       }
       catch
       {
           continue;
       }
   }
}
```

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: プログラミング／スクリプト言語の指定があれば、質問またはタグに追記した方がよいです。また可能であれば、ご自身で試された誤検知してしまうコードも提示してください。

Comment: すみません。言語はc#です。コードは、あとで提示します。スマホからなので ＞＜

Comment: 終了の誤検知とはあまり関係ないですが、排他ロックに成功した`FileStream`は`Close`せずにそのまま利用した方が良い気がします。

Comment: 確かにおっしゃることは、分かるのですが…ファイルは、その直後DLLから使用するためc#側はcloseしてます。ただ、何か方法がないか検討してみます。

Answer (score 5):

ファイルシステムから見たExcelのファイル操作は非常に複雑かつトリッキーです。
具体的に書くと、単純に「名前を付けて保存」をするだけでも、開いたり閉じたり以下のような操作をしています。

> Book3.xlsx Created / 
>   Book3.xlsx Deleted / 
>   ~$Book3.xlsx Created / Hidden, Archive, NotContentIndexed
>   ~$Book3.xlsx Changed / Hidden, Archive, NotContentIndexed
>   A4AC1610 Created / Archive
>   A4AC1610 Changed / Archive
>   A4AC1610 Changed / Archive
>   A4AC1610 Changed / Archive
>   A4AC1610 Changed / 
>   A4AC1610 renamed to Book3.xlsx

アクセス権の確認やネットワーク上の共有フォルダへの書き込み確認など、複雑な条件下でエラーなく書き込むためにこのようなプロセスになっていると思われます。
で、ご質問のケースでも厄介なのは、Excelが実ファイルとは別の一時ファイルを作成し、実ファイルを削除してから置き換える、というような処理を行っていると思われる点です。

なので、サンプルコードを見る限り、Excelのインスタンス作成はアプリから行われているようですから、このケースの場合、ファイルシステムから監視するのではなく、オートメーションでExcelを起動するアプローチがよいのではないかと思います。
以下のサンプルのように、Excel.Application()オブジェクトでExcelのインスタンスを作成し、Excel本体のイベントを受け取ることで、WorkbookBeforeCloseイベントなどを処理する手法ではいかがでしょうか?

> HOW TO: Handle Events for Excel by Using Visual C# .NET 
>   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/823981
>   方法: イベントを処理するには Visual C# を使用して優れています。NET (機械翻訳)
>   https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/kb/823981

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。やはり、excelは特別扱いする必要がありますか…。他のものも同じロジックで扱うので、特別扱いはやりたくなかったのですが、検討してみます。ホントexcelの挙動は、難解でいやらしいです ＞＜

Comment: Excelが特殊というか、おおむねOffice共通ですし、Adobe製品などもわりと大きなアプリケーションではこの手の挙動をしているのではないかと思います。
汎用的にファイルシステムから監視するならFileSystemWatcherの方が細かく情報を取れるのでいいかもしれません。とにかく粒度が細かいので、ある程度マクロ化する手間は必要になりますが。

Comment: 確かにacrobatも独特の動きをしますね。readerとで動きが異なりますし…。FileSystemWatcherも考えたのですが、更新とかは検知できますが編集終了はダメっぽいですし。イベントのとりこぼしもありそうで…。結局、アプリに合わせて行くしかないのですかね ＞＜

Answer (score 1):

言語が特定されていませんが。
EXCELしかタグがないのでEXCEL-VBA(ポーリングは…OnTime処理かな?)の前提で話しますね。

「開いているファイルのリード権」を確認というのは、`.ReadOnly`の判別方法でしょうか？

マイクロソフトのサポートのサンプルコードでは、
`Open filename For Input Lock Read as`で実際にロックかけて確認しています。
https://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb%3Bja%3B291295

こちらは試してみましたか？
またVBAかどうかも分からないので。VBA以外であれば言語も書いてください。

Comment: すみません言語は、c#でWindowsに拡張子で起動を任せたexcelです。

Answer (score 1):

少し処理を追加して、読込排他ロックが取得できた後、
一秒後に再度取得できるか試すようにしてみてはどうでしょう。

編集途中の文書ファイルを編集終了と誤判定するという現象なら、それで回避できそうです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。そうですね…確率の問題かと思うのですが、無視できるくらい低くなる可能性はありそうですね…検討してみます。

Comment: 今さら感がありますが、読込排他ロックを取得するとexcel側がエラーになってしまうタイミングがあるようです。検索すると、読込排他ロック取得が多数ヒットしますが、excel等には不向きなようです。